# How to debug "Instance of '.. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello im trying to print the value of what im receiving from a webservice in this case Firebase Auth. 
When i try to print the value it only shows "Instance of 'PlatformUser'" my guess is that there is a Object inside i can go to and search for the model but that takes some time, is there a way that i can print the whole Object in console?..

Here is my code.

```
 Future signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
try{
  AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  FirebaseUser user = result.user;
  return user;
}catch(e){
  print(e);
  return null;
}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check which Object you're working with (most likely comes as `dynamic`) use the following:

```
print('Type: ${user.runtimeType.toString()}')
```

that way you can now use `result` **as** the Object coming from the runtime type.

Example:

```
val user = result.user as PlatformUser;
// now you can use every benefits from PlatformUser while using user
```

To override `toString()` you'd need to have write access to that Object and do something like:

```
final _latLong = LatLong(4.92939, 74.912829);
print(_latLong.toString());

class LatLong {
  double lat;
  double long;

  LatLong(this.lat, this.long);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Lat: $lat - Long: $long';
  }
}
```

which prints:

```
I/flutter ( 7097): Lat: 4.92939 - Long: 74.912829
```